# How to suppress error messages when trying to access non-existent web methods on a .asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, asmx

We have a customer who are using HP Web Inspect to test for vulnerabilities in our software.

The web inspect tool is complaining about about error messages being returned when a request such as the following is made `http://host/application/WebService.asmx/MethodDoesNotExist`.

The ASP.Net framework returns a page with the following text content and a 500 status code.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

FYI: If custom errors is set to off in web.config, we also get a stack trace - like so

```
    System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Now the inspection tool is treating this result as a security vulnerability because the page has a 500 status code (so the server has admitted that an error has occurred) and also, the error message looks like it may be leaking information about the internal working of the software.  Best practise is always to show a generic, non specific error message.

The trouble is, I don't seem to have any control over this error message - it is generated by the framework and the Application_Error code is not run.

The .asmx code behind looks something like this

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class FooService 
    {
        [WebMethod(true)]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public string Bar(int fooParam)
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
```

Any ideas as to how to go about preventing this message from being generated?
I presume that the ASP.Net framework is generating the test form that it shows for simple web services - if this is the case, is there any voodoo I can use to stop it trying to generate this page?

Thanks

Chris

### Extra information

IIS 6 (Windows 2003)
ASP.Net 3.5

We tried setting a custom 500 error page in IIS but this had no effect!

The web config looks like this:

```
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/application/http500.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>

  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/GeneralError.aspx" mode="On">
        <error redirect="500.htm" statusCode="500" />
   </customErrors>
```

but the error seems not be an unhandled error and so neither 500 page is shown.

Comment: Congratulations! You've found another good reason to upgrade to WCF. ASMX has no support for your scenario.

Comment: Also, I disagree with your "security experts". It's a web service. Any operation it doesn't implement, it - surprise - doesn't implement. Yes, it might be better if there were a "something's wrong and I won't tell you what it is" return, but that's pretty minor, as "index out of range" says nothing about your code.

Comment: @John Saunders: I'm willing to be the reason why the security guys are bringing this up is because it is an essentially unhandled error.  Whether that is exploitable or not is up for discussion.

Comment: @Chris: it is not an unhandled error. Your service is never being called. It is the infrastructure which is returning the error, as should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deployed on an IIS 7 server and are using the integrated pipeline mode you can handle the errors in app: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/267/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis-70/

However, if either of those isn't true then you'll have to set a custom error page for the 500 error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This customer is using IIS and we tried setting a custom 500 error page and this had no effect - which surprised and disappointed me in equal measure.

Comment: @Chris F: was it set at the application level (web.config) or through the IIS manager?